# How can we create Interface and how to implement Interface methods in android?

Tags: android, interface

Hi I am very new for android and I have created one Utils class and there I have created one Alert Dialogue box.

When I click "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons I want to handle that click Actions in my `MainActivity` using interface methods.

But using my below code I am getting exceptions like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.venkat.implementinterfacemethods.CommonUtilities$BackGroundDialogeCall.doDialogueExecute(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

### CommonUtilities:-

```
public class CommonUtilities {

    BackGroundDialogeCall backGroundDialogeCall;

    public interface BackGroundDialogeCall {

        void doDialogueExecute(String result);
    }

    //Adding Dialoge box:-

    public void displaySignOutAlertDialog(Context activity) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setTitle("Alert")
                .setMessage("Are you sure want to reserve?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                                backGroundDialogeCall.doDialogueExecute("yes");
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                backGroundDialogeCall.doDialogueExecute("no");
                            }
                        }).show();
      }
}
```

### MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CommonUtilities.BackGroundDialogeCall {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CommonUtilities commonUtilities  = new CommonUtilities();
        commonUtilities.displaySignOutAlertDialog(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void doDialogueExecute(String result) {

        if(result.equals("yes")){
            Log.d("=======>","if block");
        }else{
            Log.d("=======>","else block");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you point out the line which gives this exception

Comment: You have not initialized backGroundDialogeCall in CommonUtilities class. Like this backGroundDialogeCall = (BackGroundDialogeCall) activity;

Comment: can u please tell how can i initialized backGroundDialogeCall in CommonUtilities class

Comment: because i am very new for android

Comment: where i have to paste ur code? u mean inside displaySignOutAlertDialog method?

Comment: Yes inside displaySignOutAlertDialog method

Comment: yes working fine thanks alot

Comment: so if i want to implement BackGroundDialogeCall interface methods in my Adapter class then also same process for initializing BackGroundDialogeCall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialized backGroundDialogeCall in CommonUtilities class that's why the null pointer exception.

You can initialize it inside your displaySignOutAlertDialog method like this:

`backGroundDialogeCall = (BackGroundDialogeCall) activity;`

For communicating between fragments and activities, check this out http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface

Note: The interface is initialized in onAttach method when using Fragments which are attached to an Activity.

For implementing interfaces other than activities; like adapters, you need a "Context" to initialize the interface.
Like this => `backGroundDialogeCall = (BackGroundDialogeCall) activity;`

Here, activity is the 'context'.

Comment: if i create interface in activity and implement method in fragment then how i iniliaze interface in activity class